# Hello all. How would you explain the ayat in surah al shams describing the moon following the sun?

Tags: science

I intend to become a practicing Muslim if all my question about Islam historically and scientifically are answered. I just feel I do not have enough information to form a decisive conclusion wither way.

Answer (score 0):

Salam alaikum my brother, may Allah (swt) make your reversion easy.

There are different interpretations of this verse. Some people think of it as metaphorically yet others think of it as literally. Here's an explanation that might help you:

When the sun sets and later disappears, it becomes night and you see the moon. When the sun rises, the moon disappears and you see the sun. So the moon follows the sun (but with a 'delay')

Comment: Please give your text with supported evidences.

Comment: This is just what my eyes scientifically see during the day-night cycle, there's no sources used for my response. Just logic.

Answer (score 0):

Most Quranic descriptions of natural events are from the basis of the anthropocentric principle.

This is a core component of the literary style of The Quranic text.

The sun and moon in the passage are described by allusion and by the day/night cycle. Please refer to:

https://quran.com/91:2/tafsirs/en-tafisr-ibn-kathir